# Application runs as scheduled task but nothing happens

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to set up a scheduled task to run an application (.exe). The application, if run manually (by double-clicking), would check a folder for new files, process them, and exit.

However, if the application is set up as an "action" in a scheduled task, when you run the scheduled task, all you see is the application starts up and appear as a process in Task Manager, but nothing else really happens. The files in the folder are not processed at all, and the process will be stuck in Task Manager, when it should shut itself down.

Any idea what's going on there? How do I get more details on what might have happened in the background?

The scheduled task is set up to run "whether user is logged on or not", with administrative privileges.

I'm running Windows 7 Professional SP1.

Update:
This is the stack output from Process Explorer:

```
ntoskrnl.exe!memset+0x61a
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xd52
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x19f
ntoskrnl.exe!__misaligned_access+0xbd0
ntoskrnl.exe!__misaligned_access+0x186d
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xf5d
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x19f
ntoskrnl.exe!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xde
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x3a23
wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x6c0
wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x4a8
wow64.dll!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0x1ce
wow64.dll!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x42a
ntdll.dll!RtlUniform+0x6e6
ntdll.dll!EtwEventSetInformation+0x1da09
ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15
kernel32.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x43
kernel32.dll!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
jvm.dll!_JVM_FindSignal@4+0x4e1df
jvm.dll!_JVM_FindSignal@4+0x8c1b1
jvm.dll!_JVM_FindSignal@4+0x8c5e6
jvm.dll!_JVM_MonitorWait@16+0xac
```

Comment: The option to run "whether user is logged on or not" uses a service-for-user (S4U) logon in the services session (i.e. session 0). Processes in this session can't directly create windows that interact with the interactive console session, so it could be hung in some GUI-related function. Use Process Explorer to show a stack trace for each thread in the process, which will provide a hint about why it's hung.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with the stack output from Process Explorer. You're right, it seems that it's stuck at waiting for some GUI feedback. Is there any way to make this work at all?

Comment: This only tells us that it's waiting on some object via `JVM_MonitorWait`, which isn't related to a display "monitor" but rather monitoring a wait. Try scheduling it to run interactively -- i.e. without an S4U logon and using the current console session's user account. If it still doesn't work, try scheduling it to run without highest privileges.

Comment: Tried "Run only when user is logged on", with and without "Run with highest privileges" checked, and in both cases I'm getting exactly the same outcome, i.e. it starts up, nothing happens, then stays running.

Comment: In Process Explorer, add the "Session" and "User Name" columns to the per-process info that's displayed in the upper pane. Make sure that it's running under the same account as Explorer and in the same session instead of session 0.

Comment: I've checked and can confirm that the app is running under the same account as explorer.exe and in the same non-zero session.

Answer (score 0):

there is an option called *Start in (optional)* while you editing *Action*. For me that helped, because my app required to have some additional resources and only could access them, when started in correct directory.

[image]